# Override jre_lib classes

Tags: overriding, java

What is the best way to override jre_lib classes?

Let's say I need to store *all* ArrayLists not in RAM but on disk or anywhere else. I wanna write my own ArrayList class to code this functionality and make sure that every instantiations of ArrayList use my class.

I thought about class loading mechanism to change order of classpath, but as I see java checks standard classes first.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Better to write all your code in terms of 'List' and then just new a class of your own that implements it.

Comment: @bmargulies: This is impossible 'cause it is third party application and there is no way to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use -Xbootclasspath to override the boot classpath